# Using two arrays with different keys in an mysql update query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

I have a array like this

```
$outputs:
  269 => string '   SUN: 2.495' (length=13)
  510 => string '   SUN: 1.416' (length=13)
```

Another Array like this

```
$filenames:
  0 => string 'Hi35
' (length=5)
  1 => string 'He_41
' (length=6)
```

And to update the respective values i tried writing a code like

```
foreach($outputs as $key => $value){
    $sql = "UPDATE Store SET D='".$value."' WHERE `Index` = '".$filenames[$key]."'";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

But then there is no `$filenames[$key] value`, because the key value for `$outputs` starts with 269. This is only one case, the key value could be anything.

I also tried the other way around. i.e.

I combined both the array first

```
$arr3 = array_combine($outputs, $filenames);
```

And then tried to Put the combined array in SQL query like

```
foreach($arr3 as $key => $value){
    $sql = "UPDATE Store SET D='".$key."' WHERE `Index` = '".$value."'";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

BUT this dint work.. A help from your side will really be appreciated...

Comment: Please do not use the `mysql_` api! It has been deprecated! Either use the mysqli or PDO Extensions! See documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Is that what you want as query? ie `UPDATE Store SET D='SUN: 2.495' WHERE Index = 'Hi35'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$outputs = array(
  '269' => 'SUN: 2.495',
  '510' => 'SUN: 1.416'
  );

$filenames = array(
  '0' => 'Hi35',
  '1' => 'He_41'
);

$array_complete = array_combine($filenames, $outputs);

foreach($array_complete as $key => $val)
{
    echo "UPDATE Store SET D='".$val."' WHERE `Index` = '".$key."'" . '<br>';
}
```

This will output

```
UPDATE Store SET D='SUN: 2.495' WHERE `Index` = 'Hi35'
UPDATE Store SET D='SUN: 1.416' WHERE `Index` = 'He_41'
```

Then I  would like to remember you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't look good at all mate, but here is a hack for that:

```
$num_outputs = count($outputs);

$index = 0;
foreach($outputs as $key => $value) {
    $sql = "UPDATE Store SET D='".$value."' WHERE `Index` = '".$index."'";
    mysqli_query($sql);
    $index++;
}
```

Comment: sorry i a newbie .. is `mysqli_query($sql)`  this means the same as `mysql_query($sql)` ??

Comment: Buddy '$i' value will stat with 0 right... and '$outputs[0]' is NULL. Because $outputs value starts with 269... As i mentioned above